ClassCastException when using Spring Data for Apache Solr in Spring Boot 3.3.x
My Spring Boot application that uses Spring Data for Apache Solr 4.3.15 runs fine using Spring Boot 3.2 (3.2.9), but produces a ClastCastException using Spring Boot 3.3 (3.3.3):
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.data.repository.query.DefaultParameters cannot be cast to class org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.SolrParameters (org.springframework.data.repository.query.DefaultParameters and org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.SolrParameters are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.SolrQueryMethod.getParameters(SolrQueryMethod.java:619) ~[spring-data-solr-4.3.15.jar:4.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.SolrParametersParameterAccessor.<init>(SolrParametersParameterAccessor.java:37) ~[spring-data-solr-4.3.15.jar:4.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.AbstractSolrQuery.execute(AbstractSolrQuery.java:112) ~[spring-data-solr-4.3.15.jar:4.3.15]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:169) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:148) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-tx-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy116.findTop20ByNewestVersionTrue(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    ...

It seems like Spring Data 3.3.x has introduced changes that cause this incompatibility. How can I get around it, knowing that Spring Data for Apache Solr is not maintained anymore?

By not using Spring Data for Apache Solr, it isn't maintained and thus eventually (which is now) it will break. So either don't upgrade or find another solution for Spring Data for Apache Solr.

Two incompatibilities for Spring Data for Apache Solr have been introduced in Spring Data 3.3.x, one in the class QueryMethod (now a createParameters(...) method with different parameters is called, which is not overridden by the subclass SolrQueryMethod) and one in the class Parameters (a constructor has been removed, which is used by the subclass SolrParameters).
You will need to patch the two classes SolrParameters and SolrQueryMethod from Spring Data for Apache Solr 4.3.15 to make them work under Spring Boot 3.3.x (and later versions) and keep them working under earlier versions:
diff -r -b src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/repository/query/SolrParameters.java src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/repository/query/SolrParameters.java
22a23
> import org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParametersSource;
30c31
<               super(method);
---
>         super(ParametersSource.of(method), SolrParameter::new);
37d37
<       @Override
diff -r -b src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/repository/query/SolrQueryMethod.java src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/repository/query/SolrQueryMethod.java
33a34,35
> import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters;
> import org.springframework.data.repository.query.ParametersSource;
612d613
<       @Override
617a619,628
>     protected Parameters<?, ?> createParameters(Method method, TypeInformation<?> domainType) {
>         return createParameters(method);
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     protected Parameters<?, ?> createParameters(ParametersSource parametersSource) {
>         return createParameters(parametersSource.getMethod());
>     }
> 
>     @Override

What has worked for me is the following:

Download the spring-data-solr source code via "git clone https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-data-solr.git -b 4.3.15".
Copy the two classes
src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/repository/query/SolrQueryMethod.java
and
src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/repository/query/SolrParameters.java
under the same package as the original into my Spring Boot
application.
Apply the patches to the two files described above.

Since Tomcat takes precedence of classes in WEB-INF/classes compared to JAR files in WEB-INF/lib (as documented in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Class_Loader_Definitions), the two patched classes are used at runtime, overriding the two classes that come from the spring-data-solr JAR file. The same applies if the embedded Tomcat is used.
